# How do I preseve a Python generator's state when changing the variable it is associated with?

Tags: python

I'm trying to traverse through a tree by iterating to a leaf, then returning to the root node and iterating down to the next leaf, until reaching the end of the tree.

When I reset the current node to root, my generator expression resets, how do I preserve it?

```
class New_node(object):
    def __init__(self, data=''):
        self.data = data
        self.children = []

    def add_child(self, obj):
        self.children.append(obj)

    def child_data(self):
        return [c.data for c in self.children]

    def select_child(self, letter):
        return self.children[self.child_data().index(letter)]

    def next_child(self):
        for c in self.children:
            yield c

for c in node.child_data()
    ...
    ...
    ...
    try:
        node = node.next_child().next()
    except StopIteration:
        node = root
```

Comment: What exactly resets? It's not obvious to me from your code.

Comment: @Reut When the StopIteration error is raised and node is set to root, it just sends itself back to the same node it went to before. I saw the post that you deleted, but I'm using Python 2.7 so I don't think I can enclose the generator.

Comment: What is it supposed to do? You're resetting back to the root...

Comment: Can you outline some expected behavior?

Comment: @Reut I'm trying to traverse the tree with a method similar to level-order, but by retrieving the data in each sub-tree. I'm not able to explain this well because I don't know what this method is called.

Comment: Well, the first step is to separate the code and explain each part. Perhaps take the time to create a minimal example someone can compile to help you. The code you've added is valid but does not compile without context. These are common tree-iteration types: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Depth-first_2

Comment: @Reut I made a diagram, but I can't upload it here due to my low reputation, please take a look. http://imgur.com/VR0sKdx

Comment: This does not explain your code at all. It's unclear to me what resets when you do not want to to reset. There are missing parts in the implementation you're giving. This is part of a class.

Comment: I've updated the code listing with the entire class. The for loop where the exception is raised just extracts data from the tree as it traverses using node.child_data().

Comment: `node = node.next_child().next()` will return always the same value.

Comment: before `for` loop, `child = node.next_child()`. In `try` block `node = child.next()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`yield` statement in a function makes it a generator. So `next_child` method is a generator. Generators are usually used in `for` loop.
To get the next element from a generator out of `for` loop, initialize the generator and call `next` function on it.

```
child = node.next_child().next

for c in node.child_data()
    ...
    ...
    ...
    try:
        node = child()
    except StopIteration:
        node = root
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand exactly what you're doing in the for loop, but here's a generator method you can iterate over.

```
def traverse(self, ancestors=list()):
    if self.children:
        for c in self.children:
            c.traverse(ancestors+[self])
    else:
        for a in ancestors:
            yield a
        yield self
```

Comment: How would I get the list of ancestors?

Comment: You iterate over it and it gives you all ancestors preceding the leaf